# No such Partition - grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grubrescue

I have a dual bootsytem on my laptop. Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. While working in windows i deleted a small and (what i thought to be) a very non important partition of 100MB. Now when i restarted the laptop, it got stuck with the grub recue (no such partiiton)

I know my data is still there of both my ubunutu and windows system. I have no other backup and i need to restore the boot again without removing any of the stored data.

Please guide me how to restore my system without having to delete any data.

I have made a photo of the terminals output. please view it here flickr.com/photos/92524026@N05/8410188685/in/photostream hope you can help me further

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i also encountered with the same error message. To be able to boot back to Windows 7 or Ubuntu you've to reinstall the Ubuntu after completion of the installation process then only you can get your Windows 7 & Ubuntu back.
 PS: Don't try any of the grub recovery techinque trust me none of them will work as i've tried all the technique yesterday to bring back the grub loader & none worked.
 So you are left with only reinstalling the Ubuntu thats the only fix.

Comment: There is plenty you can do before completely re-installing Ubuntu.  The OP wanted a way WITHOUT deleting data, so they have shown interest in using those tools.  Re-installation should be a last resort, not a first resort.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the `Boot-Rescue` tool found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If you still have the live CD that you installed ubuntu with, use option 2, and use the Reccomended settings.

Answer (score 0):

I find this is the most common issuep face. So try this now.

1. Boot using live disk of ubuntu. Use disk utility to check if your partitions are intact. If yes then proceed to next step. Do not change any thing using disk utility.
2. Open terminal and use following command :
   sudo update-grub

Once done, try a reboot. This will detect and fix menu.lst for grub configuration.

1. If this fails, try reinstalling grub. For this boot again using live disk. Open terminal and run following command:
   sudo grub-install 
   Path of disk for single sata drive computer would be /dev/sda.

Comment: I tried all the alternatives except for reinstalling ubuntu.. But i am afraid i will lose my data that was saved on my ubuntu partition if i do this..

partititions of windows and ubuntu are intact but i deleted what i think was some support partition of ubuntu filesystem. At least when i was in windows when i deleted it, windows gave the mention is was created not by windows itself..

Comment: You can use live CD to mount Linux and Windows partitions and backup imp data on external drive or other drive.

Comment: Can you provide output of sudo fdisk -l too while using live CD?

Comment: When i was using a 32bit liveusb boot-rescue in the terminal it said the filesystem is 64, and needed to use that liveusb When i put a 64bit alternate amd liveusb in, the system did not even wanted to started from the usb.. i dont know why, it just gives a beep and goes back to main menu without taking any action

Comment: Thanks Robin, I have made a photo of the terminals output.

please view it here http://www.flickr.com/photos/92524026@N05/8410188685/in/photostream

hope you can help me further

Comment: Check your processor model for support of 64bit live disk. As far as current installation is concerned, please mount Linux partition using live disk and look for /lib64 and /usr/lib64 folders, they exist then installation is 64bit else 32bit.